# Display Secure Password protected and Watermark PDF file in Browser without Password Prompt

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I need your suggestion and possible way to achieve the functionality outlined below.

I am developing the functionality to display a **PDF Document** using ASP.NET MVC using libraries like **PDF Sharp**, in order to display a Secure Password protected and Watermarked PDF file in the browser.

Challenge:
***Where PDF document should open in browser without prompting for a password but at the same time if someone downloads the file and tries to open it from the client it must ask for a password***.

Please help me or suggest to me any possible way to achieve this functionality, by using any plugin or using any other library which support it.

Thanks in advance.